# How to compare installed Linux packages between two machines

Tags: linux, versioning, package, apt-get, aptitude

I need to display a list of Linux software packages that differ in version between a ‘build machine’ and various ‘developer machines’ that can diverge over time from the build VM.

I can get quite far by doing a “dpkg –l” to obtain a text dump of the packages installed on the gold VM versus other boxes, and then doing things like a "diff" or “awk grep” on the two lists, but I wondered if there was already a tool that does a better job than me writing a script for the job.

How do you guys do this?

Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just coded this script, which compares also package versions:

https://github.com/lepe/scripts/blob/master/compare_ubuntu_apt.pl

**Usage:**

1) Generate package list in both computers, like:

```
apt --installed list | tail -n+2 > that_server.lst
```

2) Execute the perl script:

```
./compare_ubuntu_apt.pl this_server.lst that_server.lst
```

**Results: (example)**

```
----------------------------------
 DIFFERENCES 
----------------------------------
 @ apparmor : 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.2 -> 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3
 @ apt : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ apt-transport-https : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ apt-utils : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ base-files : 7.2ubuntu5.2 -> 7.2ubuntu5.3
 @ bash-completion : 1:2.1-4 -> 1:2.1-4ubuntu0.1
----------------------------------
 MISSING IN this_server.lst
----------------------------------
 + acl : 2.2.52-1
 + acpid : 1:2.0.21-1ubuntu2
 + apport : 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11
 + apport-symptoms : 0.20
 + at : 3.1.14-1ubuntu1
 + at-spi2-core : 2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1
 + attr : 1:2.4.47-1ubuntu1
 + autotools-dev : 20130810.1
----------------------------------
 MISSING IN that_server.lst
----------------------------------
 - apcupsd : 3.14.10-2build1
 - apcupsd-doc : 3.14.10-2build1
 - beep : 1.3-3
 - btrfs-tools : 3.12-1
 - discover : 2.1.2-5.2ubuntu1
```

Comment: Thank you very much lepe.  Interesting approach.  Very useful :)